# How to build Python wheels that are independent of the MacOS version?

Tags: python, macos, pip, build, python-wheel

I am regularly building and shipping Python wheels for a library, where we build different wheels for different platforms, particularly for Mac x86 and Mac ARM (M1/M2) platforms.

A resulting wheel for ARM is usually called something like `mylib-16.2.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_14_0_arm64.whl`, i.e., it not only includes the library version (16.2.0) and Python version (3.9) but also the MacOS version (14.0).

My colleagues who want to install the wheel are not all on the same MacOS version such that pip tells them there is no suitable wheel available. If I simply publish a renamed copy of the exact same wheel with a different MacOS version in the filename, the wheel is found by pip and installed properly.

Is there are way to name or build or publish the wheel such that it is independent of the MacOS *version*?
If I just omit the version from the filename `mylib-16.2.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_arm64.whl`, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `cibuildwheel` as a solution.

You can find information about it on Read the Docs:

- Local setup: https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup/
- Working examples (large/open source projects): https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working-examples/

Additionally, you can find [the source code](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel/) and a friendly community ([having many discussions](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel/discussions)) on GitHub.